how can I solve the equation $19^x+23^y=100z$ for integers $x,y,z$?
I tried to find all solution for integers $x,y,z$
$$19^x+23^y=100z$$
I tried by using $mod$ operation by taking $\mod20$ and I get
$$ 3^y\equiv_{20} (-1)^{x+1}$$
where $\equiv_{n}$ means both sides are in $\mod n$ operation
and since there is no solution for $3^y\equiv_{20} -1$ So $x$ is odd So $x=2x_1+1$
and by taking $\mod 12$ also give us $(-1)^y \equiv_{12} 4z+5$
but there is no solution for $ 4z+5 \equiv_{12} -1$ So $y=2y_1$ and we can see that $z=3z_1+2$
by taking $\mod5$ for both sides also then $(-1)^{y_1} \equiv_5 1$ So $y_1=2y_2$
So I get
$$ 19^{2x_1+1}+23^{4y_2}=100(3z_1+2)$$
now is there a general solutions for this equation ?
and how many solutions $(x,y,z)$ are there for $x+y\leq 2023$?
and is my attempt is a correct way to solving this type of equations ?

Hint: $19^x$ have period $10$ modulo $100$ and $23^y$ have period $20$ modulo $100$

There are infinitely many solutions in several different ways.
The powers of $19\pmod{100}$ repeat in cycles of $10$, and the powers of $23$ in cycles of $20$. As you have found, $x$ must be odd for $19^x+23^y$ to be a multiple of $100$, and in fact for any odd $x$ there is a choice of $y$ that works.
For example, if $x\equiv 1\pmod{10}$ then $19^x\equiv 19\pmod{100}$ and we need $23^y\equiv81\pmod{100}$, which is satisfied for any $y\equiv 8\pmod{20}$.
So $\left(10a+1, 20b+8, \frac{19^{10a+1}+23^{20b+8}}{100}\right)$ is a solution for any $a,b\in\mathbb N$, and there are similar solutions for $10a+3,10a+5,10a+7,10a+9$.

nice ideas thanks but how you got the solution for $23^y \equiv_{100} 81$ ?

@Faoler I just evaluated the powers of 23 mod 100, up to 20 since $23^{20}\equiv 23^0$ (so it just repeats after that).

Hint:
Using Binomial theorem,
$$19^{2a}=(1+360)^a=1+360a\equiv1+60a\pmod{100}$$
$$\implies19^{2a+1}\equiv19(1+60a)\equiv19+40a$$
$$23^{2b}=(530-1)^b\equiv(-1)^b+(-1)^{b-1}530b\equiv(-1)^b(1-30b)$$
$$23^{2b+1}\equiv(-1)^b23(1-30b)\equiv(-1)^b(23+10b)$$
If $b$ is odd $=2c+1$(say), the sum $19^{2a}+23^{2b}\equiv1+60a-(1-30b)\equiv60a+30(2c+1)\equiv30(2a+2c+1)$
But $2a+2c+1$ is odd, $\implies10\nmid(2a+2c+1)$
If $b$ is even $=2c$(say), $19^{2a}+23^{2(2c)}\equiv1+1\pmod{10}\not\equiv0\pmod{100}$
$19^{2a+1}+23^{2(2c)}\equiv19+40a+(1-60c)\equiv20(1+2a-3c)$
So, we need $2a-3c+1\equiv0\pmod5\iff2(a+c)\equiv-1\equiv4, a+c\equiv2\pmod5$

An experimental approach:
I could find three family of solutions which I think cover infinite solutions to this equation:
Since: $19^{10}\equiv 1 \bmod 100$
$19^3\equiv 59\bmod 100$
$\Rightarrow 19^3\times 19^{10 u}\equiv 59 \bmod 100$
Also:
$23^{20}\equiv 1\bmod 100$
$23^4\equiv 41 \bmod 100$
$\Rightarrow 23^4\times 23^{20 v}\equiv 41\bmod 100$
we have:
$\begin {cases}x=3, 13, 23, 33,\cdot\cdot\cdot (d_x=10)\rightarrow 19^x\equiv  59 \bmod 100\\y=4, 24, 44, 64\cdot\cdot\cdot(d=20)\rightarrow 23^y\equiv 41\bmod 100\\\Rightarrow 19^x+23^y\equiv (59+41=100)\bmod 100=100k+1\rightarrow z=k+1\end {cases}$
Similarly:
$\begin{cases}x=11, 21, 31, 41, \cdot\cdot\cdot (d=10)\rightarrow 19^x\equiv 19\bmod 100\\y=21, 41, 61,81\cot\cdot\cdot(d=20)\rightarrow 23^y\equiv 81\bmod 100\\\Rightarrow 19^x+23^y\equiv (19+81=100)\bmod 100=100m +100\rightarrow z=m+1\end{cases}$
$\begin{cases}x=5, 15, 25, 35, \cdot\cdot\cdot (d=10)\rightarrow 19X\equiv 99\bmod 100\\y=20^n; n\in \mathbb N\rightarrow 23^y\equiv 1\bmod 100\\\Rightarrow 19^x+23^y\equiv(99+1=100)\bmod100=100t+100\rightarrow y=t+1\end{cases}$
